# telerik gridviewdatacolumn filter not visible

Tags: silverlight, xaml, telerik, radgridview

below is my markup in my asp.net silverlight app,

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Date Discontinued"
                                                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding DISCONTINUED_TS}"
                                                    DataFormatString="{}{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}"
                                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                                    ShowFieldFilters="False" />
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Validation Date"
                                                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                    DataMemberBinding="{Binding LAST_CONFIRMED_DT}"
                                                    DataFormatString="{}{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}"
                                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                                    ShowFieldFilters="False"
                                                    />
```

and rendered output is as shown in image below,

[image]

as shown above, i am not able to get the filter for column `Validation Date`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Validation Date"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding LAST_CONFIRMED_DT}"
                            DataFormatString="{}{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            ShowFieldFilters="False"
                            IsFilterable="True"               
/>
```

Also, in your **RadGridView** definition you must set the property **IsFilteringAllowed** to **True**.